# Typo in Exercise 1.2.1.3 in "Generic figures and their glueings" on showing the equivalence of two functor categories for reflexive graphs?

Tags: category-theory, functors

I am currently working through ["Generic figures and their glueings"](https://marieetgonzalo.files.wordpress.com/2004/06/generic-figures.pdf) by Marie La Palme Reyes, Gonzalo E. Reyes and Houman Zolfaghari. Exercise 1.2.1.3 asks the following:

> Let $\Delta_1$ be the monoid of the endomorphisms of the arrow $A$ of reflexive graphs. As a category, $\Delta_1$ has one object and three arrows: $1$, $\delta_0$ and $\delta_1$ with relation $\delta_i\delta_j = \delta_i$ (where $\delta_0$ is the constant map that sends the whole arrow in its source and $\delta_1$ the arrow in its target.) Show that $\mathsf{Set}^{\Delta_1^{op}}$ may be identified with the category of reflexive graphs.

The category of reflexive graphs is defined to be the category $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathbb{C}^{op}}$ where $\mathbb{C}$ is the category generated by $V \xrightarrow{s} A$, $V \xrightarrow{t} A$, $A \xrightarrow{l} V$.

As I understand it, the exercise requires to show the equivalence of the categories $\mathsf{Set}^{\Delta_1^{op}}$ and $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathbb{C}^{op}}$.

My question: Is there a typo in the exercise? Shouldn't it be $\delta_i\delta_j = \delta_j$ instead of $\delta_i\delta_j = \delta_i$?

The equivalence of these categories (after fixing the possible typo) is also mentioned in section 2 of [reflexive graph in ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive+graph).